# WSO2 API Manager behind a loadbalancer

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to configure WSO2 API Manager behing an apache that works as a loadbalancer, in order to have HA of the API. 
I'd like to configure 2 URL:
- apiweb.mycompany.com for store,publisher (port 80 & 443)
- api.mycompany.com for the gateway (port 10080for http & 10443 for https)

I configure the apache side with the http balancer between the two API nodes. What do I have to configure on APIM side to have such behaviour? Right now, APIM publish my api on the IP address of the servers where it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You shoudl change the axis2.xml file. There is a parameter named "WSDLEPRPrefix". Point this value to the fully qualified name, example:

```
    <parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">http://your_hostname-of_apache_server.com</parameter>
```